# Check existence of an object inside a for loop in twig

Tags: object, twig

I'm trying to figure out how to check the existance of an object while doing a for loop in twig.

This is how my code looks like.

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    {% set id = topic.id %}
    {% set ratings = authRatings.id %}

    {% if ratings is defined %}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

topic.id is the needle and authRatings is a haystack of different objects named after its topic_id. If an object match the topic.id ratings should be defined.

```
object
(stdClass)[76]
  public '24' => 

object
(stdClass)[77]
      public 'topic_id' => string '24' (length=2)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'likes' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dislikes' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'time' => string '1348927295' (length=10)
  public '15' => 

object
(stdClass)[78]
      public 'topic_id' => string '15' (length=2)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'likes' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'dislikes' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'time' => string '1348927363' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom function that does the job. something like this:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction('searchRatings', new Twig_Function_Function('twig_search_ratings'));
function twig_search_ratings($topic_id, $ratings) {
   /* do the search in php */
}
```